# Linq query Left Join condition

Tags: linq, join, conditional-statements

I'm trying to recreate the following sql query using Linq syntax, for some reason it is not working, please let me know what am I doing wrong here

### My sql query:

```
select 
cf.VisitConfigId,
cf.VisitName,
sv.VisitDate 
from SubjectVisitConfig cf 
left join SubjectVisit sv on cf.VisitConfigId = sv.VisitConfigId
```

### My Linq query:

```
var q = from cf in ctms.SubjectVisitConfigs
        join sv in ctms.SubjectVisits on cf.VisitConfigId equals  
        sv.VisitConfigId into JoinedVisits
        from sv in JoinedVisits.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where sv.SubjectId == subjectId.Value && sv.SiteId == siteId.Value
        select new
        {
            sv.VisitId,
            VisitDate = sv.VisitDate != null ? sv.VisitDate : null,
            cf.VisitName
        };
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you define "not working"?

Comment: I'm sorry, by not working I mean that it is return data but only if there is an exact match 1-1 between the two tables, want to pull up data from SubjectVisitConfigs table regardless if there is data in the SubjectVisits table or not

Answer (score 3):

You're dereferencing `sv` unconditionally in your select clause - but `sv` will be logically null for items which don't have a matching `SubjectVisit`. How would you expect your `where` clause to match any result where `sv` is null?

Here's *one* possible rewrite:

```
var q = from cf in ctms.SubjectVisitConfigs
        join sv in ctms.SubjectVisits
                       .Where(x => x.SubjectId == subjectId.Value && 
                              x.SiteId == siteId.Value)
             on cf.VisitConfigId equals sv.VisitConfigId into JoinedVisits
        from sv in JoinedVisits.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            VisitId = sv == null ? null : sv.VisitId,
            VisitDate = sv == null ? null : sv.VisitDate,
            cf.VisitName
        };
```

Comment: @Alex: Do you understand *why* `DefaultIfEmpty` is used to emulate left joins, and what the result is? You get a row where `sv` is null when an inner join wouldn't have given any results. Now look at your `where` clause...

Comment: @Alex: Hard to say without knowing what you're trying to achieve. I'll edit with *one* possible option...